# Removing surface contamination from Langmuir probe during glow discharge in residual atmospheric gases

Tags: plasma-physics

I am writing this question to ascertain if it is possible to clean a Langmuir probe by biasing the probe negatively or positively with respect the plasma potential, during a glow discharge with oxygen present. The vacuum system is evacuated to moderate vacuum pressures around about a millibar. A glow discharge is then struck using applied DC power. I have tried using different probe materials, tungsten wire was initially used and was initially abrasively cleaned. A black coating was observed during later inspection. More recently stainless steel wire was also tested, no coloration was observed on the stainless. A mechanical pencil lead was also tested and darkening of surface was observed.

Unfortunately I haven't taken any screenshots or photos of the recent tests using the pencil lead or the stainless wire. I have included an old photo of the oscilloscope trace using the tungsten wire.

Doing some research it looks like the shape of the curve is due to capacitive and resistive effects of[image: Oscilloscope trace] surface contamination.

I am considering designing a circuit which disconnects the probe from a measurement circuitry and instead applies a potential to the probe before measurement. I am unsure if it would be best to apply a negative or positive potential and if removal of surface contamination is possible in air plasma. I am concerned that my proposed solution in air plasma will only further contaminate the surface with oxides.

Comment: Isn't the point of an oxygen plasma to clean something by oxidizing anything oxidizable? Of course you will get oxides on the surface of tungsten. I would expect graphite to be eaten away. Stainless steel has a passive surface, so it would not be affected. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langmuir_probe shows a titanium probe with a titanium nitride coating. Would a coating be possible?